# Preview a Theme in Magento Commerce

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, frontend, theme

Is it possible to preview a theme I'm working on? I am creating a new theme for a Magento website but do not want my changes to be live on the main store until I am happy.

Is there a way to preview a theme in the admin panel or make theme-selection possible for logged in admins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only and easiest way to do this is to create a new `store view` and apply the theme to that one.
This way all settings, products and categories will be the same but using the new template.

If you also want to experiment with settings you're probably better off creating a new `website` instead of `store view`.

Comment: And it is possible to make this new store non-public?

Comment: you can put it on a subdomain like `staging.domain.com` and remove the store switcher that is provided in the base theme. To require login on this shop might be a bit trickier. You can try using https://github.com/sandermangel/rkstorelogin which is stable. Used it in 2 other projects on Mage 1.8.1.0

Comment: If I enable a new store view I get the following full body error message on both my normal view and the new one:

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'sdksales_mage1.mage_catalog_category_flat_store_5' doesn't exist

Comment: and it doesn't create the new storeview? Sounds like you have some issues in your installation then. Normally Magento would create a new flat category data table automatically and fill it during indexing.

Comment: Yeah, after a few refreshes the error disappears but now the site has a half-loaded default theme (not the one I'm currently using as a jumping off point).

Hmmm..

Comment: I've created a new store + storeview under that, but I've no idea how to navigate to that.

Comment: under `System > Configuration > General > Web` you can set the base url. Choose either a subdirectory or preferably if possible a subdomain. Make sure you change the scope to the new storeview when you change the settings. These links will help you with setting it up properly: http://www.crucialwebhost.com/kb/how-to-setup-multiple-magento-stores/, https://www.properhost.com/members/knowledgebase/30/How-to-Setup-Magento-with-Multiple-Stores-and-Domains.html, http://www.rabbitpills.com/2013/04/28/setup-multidomain-and-subdomain-for-magentos-websites/